# re-adding a view to the view controller from another class

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller

I add a `UIView`, `minimisedInterface`, to my view controller as normal

```
[self.view addSubview:minimisedInterface];
```

`minimisedInterface` is removed from the view controller, on a button tap.

```
[self removeFromSuperview];
```

I now want to re-add the `minimisedInterface` to the view controller, but on a button tap in another class, `Interface`. 
What is the correct way to do this? I was considering getting a handle on the view controller from the `Interface` class but this seems a little counter-intuitive, as if one shouldn't "control" the view controller itself.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two likeliest ways that come to mind are:

- make the view controller a delegate of the Interface class and have a [delegate presentView]; method (or something of the kind)
- send a NSNotification that the view is needed again, from the buttons IBAction, and have the view controller listen for that notification.